# The left annihilator of idempotent elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

$R$ is a ring with identity.If $\ \pi\in R\ $ is an idempotent element ($\pi^2=\pi$),How to prove $\operatorname{ann}_\text{l}(\pi)=R(1-\pi)$? where $\operatorname{ann}_\text{l}(\pi)$ represents the left annihilator of $\ \pi\ $.

I know how to prove $R(1-\pi)\subset\operatorname{ann}_\text{l}(\pi)$.i want to prove $\operatorname{ann}_\text{l}(\pi)\subset R(1-\pi)$ to complete the proof.

$\alpha\in \operatorname{ann}_\text{l}(\pi)\Rightarrow\alpha\pi=0$. And I want to prove $\alpha=r(1-\pi)$ for some $r\in R$. But I have no idea, can someone give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: What is $\alpha(1-\pi)$?

Comment: @Allen Bell ! Thank you very much, You reminded me with one sentence。

Comment: Notice that $\alpha=\alpha(\pi+1-\pi)=\alpha\pi+\alpha(1-\pi)=\alpha(1-\pi)$